# How to invoke an Adobe Air based desktop app from an other Adobe Air based desktop app?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, desktop-application, invoke, launcher

How to invoke an Adobe Air based desktop app from an other Adobe Air based desktop app?
I found this undocumented solution, but it seems to no longer work:

```
    import adobe.utils.ProductManager;
    private var pm:ProductManager;

    private var appID:String = "LauncherSample";
    private var pubID:String = "123456789";

    private function launchApp():void{
        var mgr:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");
        mgr.launch("-launch " + appID + " " + pubID);
    }
```

I'm using Adobe Air SDK 4 with Flash CS 6.

Comment: Have you tried http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

Comment: TreeTree is right. You have to use Native Processes to call an application inside your own app. But this means you have to build your application as a Native Installer or as a Captive Runtime. A common .air application does not support Native Processes. Beware of this fact.

Comment: @PaulFacklam Thanks for pointing that out! Do you know if it's possible to pass arguments to an app? (e.g. to share a message)

Comment: @Tom: Of course you can. See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html